# Google OCR Addon G1ANT Studio

Tags: g1ant

While using the google **OCR addon** in the G1ANT Studio, I fount that even after entering appropriate API Key or JSON Credentials, I was unable to log into my google cloud service account and it kept giving me an error saying that the entered credentials were incorrect.

Anyone else experiencing a similar problem? Please help out!

PS: I've already enabled the **Google vision** API in the developers console under a specified project name.

*Thanks in Advance!*

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem by using the API key instead of JSON Credential and also by a slight alteration in the code, as shown below:

**ocrgoogle.login chrome apikey "Your API Key"**

as you can see, we have to enter chrome (application name) for the command to run as intended.

Have fun!